# Comma lost, converted to ampersand when encoding address

Tags: php, urlencode

I have an address along the lines of the following:

> 123 Main Street, Boston Massachusetts, 02137

I need an address to remain intact through a URL so I tried the following:

```
echo urlencode($address);
echo rawurlencode($address);
```

The problem is that the commas keep being converted in to ampersands! ︎

How do I prevent (the client? PHP? I'm not sure here) it from converting commas in to ampersands?

The HTTP query is `address` and the following is what happens:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

Yields:

> Array (
>
> [address] => 123 Main Street
>
> [Boston_Massachusetts] =>
>
> [02137] =>
>
> )

Comment: Show us the actual output. Encoding like this usually converts them to `%2C`

Answer (score 2):

If they're getting converted to ampersands, something is going horribly wrong, as both `urlencode` and `rawurlencode` convert commas to `%2C`.

Encoding the string `123 Main Street, Boston Massachusetts, 02137` with `rawurlencode` 
should give you `123%20Main%20Street%2C%20Boston%20Massachusetts%2C%2002137`.

From here it's simply a matter of using `rawurldecode` when reading back from the URL to convert the encoded string back to your original string:

```
$address = "123 Main Street, Boston Massachusetts, 02137";
echo $address; // 123 Main Street, Boston Massachusetts, 02137

$encoded = rawurlencode($address);
echo $encoded; // 123%20Main%20Street%2C%20Boston%20Massachusetts%2C%2002137

$decoded = rawurldecode($encoded);
echo $decoded; // 123 Main Street, Boston Massachusetts, 02137
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://3v4l.org/97JfW)**.